# Using Chrome's Developer Tools to edit the page live with new global CSS rules

Tags: css, google-chrome, live, developer-tools

It's easy enough in [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) to inspect an element and [edit an existing CSS rule applying to that element](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles#styles_edit) but what if you want to create a whole new style rule?

In my case what I wanted to do was apply the following style rules:

br {display: none}
   hr {margin-top: 20px}
   font {font-size: 18px}

To the [Principles behind the Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html) so that I could print it out on one A4 sheet of paper directly from the browser.

The official document on Chrome Developer Tools that I've already linked to does have a section on [Adding New Rules and Properties](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles#styles_add_new) but it's out of date and doesn't work like that in the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: i think almost people know this ...........

Comment: Okay, well I had trouble finding it and I've been using CDT for years. You can vote to delete it if you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now a dedicated button in the `Styles` pane for "New Style Rule". It looks like a plus (+):

[image: new style button]

This will create a new style block which will allow you to define the selector yourself:

[image: effect of new style button]

Comment: Spent ages trying to find out why this isn't working for me.  Turns out there's a bug when using Adblock Plus extension.  Posting this comment in case others land here while trying to find source of bug.

Comment: Also see [this chromium bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160974) which can cause problems with the inspector stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

This is handy for little amendments on the fly, however it doesn't work well for CSS3 media queries that need extra curly brackets, or for pasting whole sections of CSS in to test.

The solution to that is to first click on the **+** button to add a new style, then hit enter (or click in the adjacent whitespace).

This will now show a link to the inspector stylesheet called **inspector-stylesheet:1**

If you click that link, it opens a whole live stylesheet that you can write complex rules in, as well as paste a whole external stylesheet into for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CSS Brush](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-brush/mamnhhinmmdpcipjnhflillmhnogoobj?hl=en-US), a chrome plugin to create CSS live. You can create selectors from the page. You can have the complete CSS path or filter it up to make a shorter one. The context-sensitive menu is quite helpful while editing CSS properties live. You can even switch on/off properties or selectors.